# JBoss 7 Statup Fails

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

This is an Eclipse Juno project using JDK7 and I can't get JBoss7 to start up.  The error mentions LoopLimitCheck, but that's a red herring, other devs on the same project have that option and it is fine.

I've tried all the obvious stuff like paths and making sure everyone is using the same JVM, etc.  to no avail.

Here is the output of the ant script:

```
Buildfile: C:\workspaces\tee_git\tee_build\build\build.xml
   [echo] Loaded user specified filters from:  C:\tee/tee.localhost.filter.properties
confirm-jboss-mgmt:
start-jboss:
 [exec] Calling "C:\workspaces\tee_git\tee_build\jboss7\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
 [exec] Running JBoss in debug mode
 [exec] ===============================================================================
 [exec]   JBoss Bootstrap Environment
 [exec]   JBOSS_HOME: C:\workspaces\tee_git\tee_build\jboss7
 [exec]   JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java
 [exec]   JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=debug.bat -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xrs -Dhibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -XX:-UseLoopPredicate -XX:-LoopLimitCheck -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
 [exec] ===============================================================================
 [exec] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
 [exec] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
 [exec] Improperly specified VM option 'LoopLimitCheck'
 [exec] Press any key to continue . . . 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a clear error message -- read it & work from there. **Maybe your JVM is a different version, or you need to turn on special/experimental options?** Or you've got some contradictory flags.

Try adding:  **-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions**

See:  https://community.oracle.com/thread/2587527 -- which would strongly suggest you're not actually running the exact same JVM version as the others in your project.

If removing the indicated flag really isn't the answer, my general expectation of a competent developer would be: Do a binary search on your JVM options, as to what works/ what doesn't, and have a look at the JVM source-code. Reading that can be illuminating as to how the options work (& what they actually do).

It's not really JBoss here, it's JVM. The JVM won't accept or start with flags it doesn't like. Your job is to understand those flags better, to find out why.

Comment: At least in regard of one bug that required the `-XX:-UseLoopPredicate -XX:-LoopLimitCheck` workaround, Oracle believe they've fixed the bug in Java 7 and these flags are not longer required. See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html#javase7changes http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5091921